# Flow Typechecking Questions

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm new to Flow and am wondering why a couple 'basic' issues don't raise any warnings in Flow:

```
  let foo: Array<{| id: string, occursOn: string |}>;
  foo = [{ id: "5", occursOn: "2017-01-01" }];

  // Not a flow error!
  console.log(foo[0][0].bar);

  const grouped = groupBy(foo, "occursOn");

  // Not a flow error!
  console.log(grouped["2017-01-01"].bar);
```

Why is accessing `foo[0][0].bar` ok in Flow, when I have been explicit about the type of `foo`?

Similarly, I have `lodash` installed via `flow-typed`, yet `grouped["2017-01-01"].bar` seems to be totally fine in Flow?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example with the array index seems like this bug: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4257

For the `groupBy`, most likely you just haven't told Flow what `groupBy` does. I'd assume you're doing

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash';
```

and by default Flowtype doesn't have any way to know what the `lodash` module is or what its functions do, so [you need to install type definitions for Lodash](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed), and hope that you're not using too much runtime magic so it'll give you a reasonable type signature.

For your case, you do get the error when Flow knows what type it is, [which you can see here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjSgCYFMDG0CGAnDUAFwE8AHIgfQDVdoBXDAeQDtpSBJYjfXHjAB4AKgD5QAXlAAKAG70mALlDCAlJPEBbAJYAPDGgDcKdNjyESFInUYt2XHnwEjxU2grsduvfhiFjQAB9QAGdifG1WAHNjVFRMHAIiSAZWLGJtWFZQKPxYBnIAIVJBGgAaFVFpEzjQAj5SZQB+AEF8BpcymrjtR18MJuUbJjYvPucxbtVlAG9QAG0AawxG0BoAXWU2joCAX2MTLCyw0EhYWC323BKZ4O00ZTCI6IrYLCwGfBC2R-DIqKCu1cCzm92UACIAKzg17vT7fVgQgBMAAYAIwAdgAtOicWjwaBdutYqBDsdiDk8gUDJJKfkiqRpGdYBVwW8Pl82ODVAdUCBQAA5WAU3CnODwUC8PL4ACEZNYIVg0AwADo4FFpLl6QZ5uDUZi8XjwesVQAjAg8oA).

Comment: Many thanks.

For the `groupBy` part of your question, as mentioned in my original post, I have installed definitions for lodash via `flow-typed`. It turns out that because I was cherry picking my module (to avoid loading the entire lodash library into my bundle) via `import groupBy from "lodash/groupBy"`, this was not correctly picked up by `flow-typed`. Switching to `import { groupBy } from 'lodash'` works.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that part of the comment. That makes sense. If you still want to avoid pulling the whole bundle while using the types, you can use something like https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash.